# Install MongoDB on Debian Buster

Tags: mongodb, debian, stretch, sid

How to install the latest MongoDB 3.4 or even 3.6?
They support with Ubuntu, but my server is Debian Buster and I am stuck with MongoDB 3.2.

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source

Comment: I have found the solution for a build script, the description is found here: https://github.com/patrikx3/docker-debian-testing-mongodb-stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution for a build script, the description is found here:

https://github.com/patrikx3/docker-debian-testing-mongodb-stable

The description:

Debian Stretch / Buster / Bullseye / Testing MongoDB and MongoDB Tools build stable builder script, what it does as exactly:

It is basically a built for the latest MongoDB for Debian.

The current varsion is the r4.0.x build (release).

Warning It will remove all mongodb* apt packages in ./scripts/build-server.sh and /etc/systemd/system/mongodb-server.service is replaced.

It install the required apt dependencies and generates the SystemD service and makes it enabled.

Check if the build works (building is below). It runs all tests, so if it works, then it really does, actually. If there is an error, of course, you will not deploy on your server. So, if building and testing works, then it puts the binaries as it follow and you are sure and done.

The build as follows `build-server.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# based on https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source

# the current directory
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

# if an error exit right away, don't continue the build
set -e

# some info
echo
#echo "Works like command, use a tag: sudo ./scripts/build-server.sh r4.2.0"
echo "Works like command, use a tag: sudo ./scripts/build-server.sh r4.0.12"
echo

# check if we are root
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be ran via root 'sudo' command or using in 'sudo -i'."
   exit 1
fi

# require mongo branch
#if [ -z "${1}" ]; then
#    echo "First argument must be the MONGODB_BRANCH for example 'v4.1'"
#    exit 1
#fi
#MONGODB_BRANCH="${1}"

# require mongo release
#if [ -z "${2}" ]; then
#    echo "The second argument must be the MONGODB_RELEASE for example 'r4.1.0'"
#    exit 1
#fi
#MONGODB_RELEASE="${2}"

# require mongo release
if [ -z "${1}" ]; then
    echo "The first argument must be the MONGODB_RELEASE for example 'r4.0.12'"
    exit 1
fi
MONGODB_RELEASE="${1}"

# delete all mongo other programs, we self compile
apt remove --purge mongo*

# the required packages for debian
apt -y install libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-thread-dev build-essential gcc python scons git glibc-source libssl-dev python-pip libffi-dev python-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev #libcurl-dev
pip install -U pip pyyaml typing


# generate build directory variable
BUILD=$DIR/../build

# delete previous build directory
rm -rf $BUILD/mongo

# generate new build directory
mkdir -p $BUILD

# the mongodb.conf and systemd services files in a directory variable
ROOT_FS=$DIR/../artifacts/root-filesystem

# find out how many cores we have and we use that many
if [ -z "$CORES" ]; then
    CORES=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)
fi
echo Using $CORES cores

# go to the build directory
pushd $BUILD

    # clone the mongo by branch
    #git clone -b ${MONGODB_BRANCH} https://github.com/mongodb/mongo.git

    # clone the mongo by branch
    git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo.git

    # the mongo directory is a variables
    MONGO=$BUILD/mongo

    # go to the mongo directory
    pushd $MONGO

        # checkout the mongo release
        git checkout tags/${MONGODB_RELEASE}

        # hack to old version python pip cryptography from 1.7.2 to use the latest
        sed -i 's#cryptography == 1.7.2#\#cryptography == 1.7.2#g' buildscripts/requirements.txt
        # this is only because 4.0.12 uses 1.7.2 and
        # https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/4193#issuecomment-381236459
        # support minimum latest (2.2)
        pip install cryptography

        # install the python requirements
        #pip install -r etc/pip/dev-requirements.txt
        pip install -r buildscripts/requirements.txt

        # somewhere in the build it says if we install this, it is faster to build
        pip2 install --user regex

        # build everything
        scons all --disable-warnings-as-errors -j $CORES --ssl

        # install the mongo programs all
        scons install --disable-warnings-as-errors -j $CORES --prefix /usr

        # create a copy of the old config
        #TIMESTAMP=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
        #cp /etc/mongodb.conf /etc/mongodb.conf.$TIMESTAMP.save

        # copy the mongodb.conf configured and the systemd service file
        # dangerous!!! removed
        # cp -avr $ROOT_FS/. /

        MONGODB_SERVICE=etc/systemd/system/mongodb-server.service
        cp $ROOT_FS/$MONGODB_SERVICE /$MONGODB_SERVICE
        chown root:root /$MONGODB_SERVICE
        chmod o-rwx /$MONGODB_SERVICE

        # generate mongodb user and group
        useradd mongodb -d /var/lib/mongodb -s /bin/false || true

        # create the required mongodb database directory and add safety
        mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb
        chmod o-rwx -R /var/lib/mongodb
        chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb

        # create the required mongodb log directory and add safety
        mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb
        chmod o-rwx -R /var/log/mongodb
        chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb

        # create the required run socket directory and add safety
        mkdir -p /run/mongodb
        chmod o-rwx -R /run/mongodb
        chown -R mongodb:mongodb /run/mongodb

        # add safety to the mongodb config file
        chmod o-rwx /etc/mongodb.conf || true
        chown mongodb:mongodb /etc/mongodb.conf || true

        # reload systemd services
        systemctl daemon-reload

        # enable the mongodb-server
        systemctl enable mongodb-server

        # start the mongodb-server
        #service mongodb-server start

    # exit of the mongo directory
    popd

# exit the build directory
popd

# delete current build directory
rm -rf $BUILD/mongo
```

The build as follows `build-tools.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# based on https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools

# the current directory
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

# if an error exit right away, don't continue the build
set -e

# some info
echo
echo "Works like command: sudo ./scripts/build-tools.sh r4.0.12"
echo

# check if we are root
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be ran via root 'sudo' command or using in 'sudo -i'."
   exit 1
fi

# require mongo release
if [ -z "${1}" ]; then
    echo "The first argument must be the MONGODB_RELEASE for example 'r4.0.12'"
    exit 1
fi
MONGODB_RELEASE="${1}"

## delete all mongo other programs, we self compile
##apt remove --purge mongo*

## the required packages for debian
##apt -y install gcc python scons git glibc-source libssl-dev python-pip

apt -y install golang libpcap-dev

export GOROOT=$(go env GOROOT)


# generate build directory variable
BUILD=$DIR/../build/src/github.com/mongodb/

# delete previous build directory
rm -rf $BUILD/mongo-tools

# generate new build directory
mkdir -p $BUILD

# find out how many cores we have and we use that many
CORES=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)

# go to the build directory
pushd $BUILD

    # clone the mongo by branch
    git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools

    # the mongo directory is a variables
    MONGO_TOOLS=$BUILD/mongo-tools

    # go to the mongo directory
    pushd $MONGO_TOOLS

        # checkout the mongo release
        git checkout tags/${MONGODB_RELEASE}

        bash ./build.sh
        chown root:adm -R ./bin
        chmod o-rwx -R ./bin
        chmod ug+rx ./bin/*
        cp -r ./bin/. /usr/bin
#        for PROGRAM in bsondump mongodump mongoexport mongofiles mongoimport mongoreplay mongorestore mongostat mongotop
#        do
#            go build -o bin/${PROGRAM} -tags "ssl sasl" ${PROGRAM}/main/${PROGRAM}.go
#        done

    # exit of the mongo directory
    popd

# exit the build directory
popd

# delete current build directory
rm -rf $BUILD/mongo-tools
popd

# delete current build directory
rm -rf $BUILD/mongo-tools
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is a good idea yet, but I just installed it by adding the `sid` repos and installing using the `mongodb-server` package. For me this installs version 3.4.18.

I created `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sid.list` with:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ sid main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ sid main
```

then did

```
apt update
apt install mongodb-server
```

and verified that it's working by connecting with `mongo`.